# How to monthly update every users free credits? (change one column of every row of a users table)

Tags: vercel, supabase, supabase-database

My app gives new users a free amount of monthly credits to use.

Every month I want to modify many rows of my users table if they are on the free plan.

So my API call might be something like:
supabase.from("users").update({ "app_credits: 100 }).eq("plan", "free");

So I want to modify multiple rows - anyone who is plan=free gets 100 credits at the start of each month.

I could setup a Vercel cron job to run once a month with Javascript to call the supabase API above. But how would I setup authentication for that backend only code? How would I setup auth to allow editing multiple user data?

Or is there a way inside Supabase I can get it to monthly run an SQL update query to perform what I need across multiple user rows?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.

In Supabase you can enable the Postgres cron extension.

https://supabase.com/blog/postgres-as-a-cron-server

In your dashboard under databases you should then see a "Cron" schema.

In the cron.job table you can manually insert a cron job: put the sql in "command" column and the cron details (such as "0 0 1 * *") in the "schedule" column.

The results will be in the cron.job_run_details table.

I hope this helps someone.